# Issue while reading "User level" environment variable in powershell EPS file

Tags: powershell, operating-system

One of my EPS file's reads a particular environment variable "PARAM_KEY" and passes it as an argument to one of my PS scripts. The environment variable is a "USER LEVEL" one.

```
"Arguments": "<%= Get-LocalIpAddress -%> <%= $ENV:PARAM_KEY -%>"
```

I noticed that the in the EPS file, PS is not able to read this environment variable and hence my function errors out.

I changed the variable from **USER Level** to **System Level**

Retried the same and it worked.

Comment: You seem to have resolved your own problem - what is your question?

Comment: Did you verify that the variable is defined for the user that is running the script?

Comment: I wuild suspect the script has permission to access system variables but not the user ones, which are stored in the user profile?